# Facebook PHP SDK missing Session

Tags: php, facebook

I am discovering the Facebook PHP SDK and I have some issue getting user pages where he is admin.
I use the code given to me by the graph api explorer

```
<?php
session_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '0000000000000',
  'app_secret' => '00000000000',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/accounts'
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

var_dump($response);
?>
```

I get :

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: session in C:\wamp\www\testapi\fb_affiche.php on line 17

Ok i get it so i find this :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/5.0.0

My composer.json :

```
{
  "require": {
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "^0.6.2",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.1.2"
  }
}
```

I dont have the class `FacebookSession`.
So how can i get the user pages ?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of SDK you are using?

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like i said i dont have the FacebookSession file.
I make it work like that :

```
    $fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => '00000000000',
  'app_secret' => '000000000000',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

$request = $fb->request('GET', "/me/accounts", [], $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
$body = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content of a file Facebook PHP-SDK 4.0.9.

```
// You need to include this class

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession as FacebookSession;

    $request = new FacebookRequest(  
      // Write below line should be
      FacebookSession $session,  
      ....,
      ....,
    );
```

Hope it will help you :)